# Get Map<String, List<Object>> from List<Object> where the key is one of the fields of the objects

Tags: java, dictionary, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I've got an object as below

```
public class Model {
    private String key;
    private String data1;
    private String data2;
    private String data3;

    // getters
}
```

A list of these Models is being returned via the data layer.
Now I want to create a `Map<String, List<Model>>` with the key being the "key" field in the `Model`class.
There are multiple duplicate "key"s with different data values.
I have the below existing solution but need a simpler and better way. Haven't used Java 8 extensively so not quite familiar with most of the methods and need a solution soon as I don't have time to research.

```
List<Model> models = modelRepo.getAllModels();
Set<String> keys = models.stream().map(Model::getKey).collect(Collectors.toSet());

Map<String, List<Model>> result = new HashMap<>();
keys.stream().forEach(key -> {
    List<Model> modelList = new ArrayList<>();
    models.stream().forEach(model -> {
        if (model.getKey().equals(key)) {
            modelList.add(model);
        }
    });
    result.put(key, modelList);
});
```

Comment: You might want `groupingBy`

Comment: That worked. Thanks a lot @user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `groupingBy` for grouping Models by `key` which return Map

```
Map<String, List<Model>> results = models.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Model::getKey));
```

`groupingBy` method which only takes a function as its parameter. The value that is returned by the function is used as a key to the map that we get from the groupingBy collector.

Comment: right idea, but no need for this `Collectors.mapping(d-> d, Collectors.toList())`

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `stream().forEach()` can be replaced with `forEach()` as long as no intermediate operations are used.

What you want is a typical use-case for `Collectors.groupingBy` with no further downstream collector:

```
Map<String, List<Model>> result = models.stream()     // Stream<Model>
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Model::getKey));   // Map<String, List<Model>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use groupingBy:

```
public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Model> models = new ArrayList<>();
        models.add(new Model("a", "a1", "a2", "a3"));
        models.add(new Model("a", "a4", "a5", "a6"));
        models.add(new Model("c", "c1", "c2", "c3"));
        models.add(new Model("d", "d1", "d2", "d3"));
        models.add(new Model("d", "d4", "d5", "d6"));

        Map<String, List<Model>> result = models.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Model::getKey));

        result.forEach((a, b) -> System.out.println(a + " - " + b));
    }

    public static class Model {
        private String key;
        private String data1;
        private String data2;
        private String data3;

        public Model(String key, String data1, String data2, String data3) {
            this.key = key;
            this.data1 = data1;
            this.data2 = data2;
            this.data3 = data3;
        }

        public String getKey() {
            return key;
        }

        public void setKey(String key) {
            this.key = key;
        }

        public String getData1() {
            return data1;
        }

        public void setData1(String data1) {
            this.data1 = data1;
        }

        public String getData2() {
            return data2;
        }

        public void setData2(String data2) {
            this.data2 = data2;
        }

        public String getData3() {
            return data3;
        }

        public void setData3(String data3) {
            this.data3 = data3;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Model{" +
                    "key='" + key + '\'' +
                    ", data1='" + data1 + '\'' +
                    ", data2='" + data2 + '\'' +
                    ", data3='" + data3 + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well for starters, the elegant way is that you can use the `groupBy` in `stream()`.

```
Map<String, List<Model>> results = models.stream()
                                         .collect( Collectors.groupingBy(Model::getKey));
```

And if you are reluctant to use `stream()`, And also since  you mention that you haven't used Java 8 extensively so not quite familiar with most of the methods. There's always the traditional way of doing this with loops.

```
    Map<String,List<Model>> results = new HashMap<>(  );

    for( Model m : models )
    {
        if( results.containsKey( m.getKey() ) )
        {
            results.get( m.getKey() ).add( m );
        }
        else
        {
            results.put( m.getKey(), new ArrayList<>( Collections.singleton(m) ) );
        }
    }
```